# How to programme EOS utility to take n number of shots?

Tags: canon, dslr, software, shooting-technique, remote

I just installed the EOS utility program and wanted to know if it's possible to tell the program to take let's say 10 or 15 or 40 shots in a row, well you get the idea.

Comment: page 38 of the manual might be helpful http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/2/0300001682/01/eu2.5a-m-en.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure about EOS Utilities working for the number of shots in a row but an Android App Called DSLR Controller (Beta) works really well with my T4i and when i had a T2i. I havent tested it for the 7D mark ii yet. If you can get a micro usb to micro usb or an android tablet with a USB Port for the standard cord. the app lets you program lots of settings like number of pictures, at how many seconds apart, aperture, shutter speed, iso, change settings by brightness after each photo, etc.

I used it for a time lapse of completing the patio in my backyard a few years back and it worked pretty well, to make a time laps of my buddies wedding head table, to get self photos where 10 seconds isn't enough time to get behind the camera, review my RAW images while I'm on the road some where and want to see it on a larger screen.

I would really recommend looking into it and see if it might work for your Canon Camera.

[DSLR Controller (BETA)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.dslrcontroller) - it costs about $7.99 (CAD or USD, i forget)

[Remote Release](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.remoterelease) - A Test app before purchasing the DSLR Controller

Comment: I tried the free app, It can not find my camera, even though the wifi is on and configured to my network, I tried with the usb cable too, doesn't work... I have no idea what may be the problem. I can connect with the eos remote app though

Comment: I'm using 70D btw

Comment: Nevermind, I did a mistake by choosing the infrastructure mode in camera wi-fi settings, I changed it to Camera acess point and now it works.

Comment: Also what do you think is the best interval between shots, is the 100ms good for the camera?

Comment: your shutter speed can manage 0.1s, if your FPS is fast enough, i like it more for a 2 shots per second or 1 shot per minute kind of speeds while having the shutter speed to 1/100. really play with the app and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to program a specific number of shots with EOS Utility. It is also possible to define the interval between shots and the shutter speed and aperture value for each shot. You can also set it to do exposure bracketing as well.

For more about the capabilities of EOS Utility, please see [*Getting the Most From EOS Utility*](http://cpn.canon-europe.com/content/product/canon_software/eos_utility.do).

Here's a direct link to an older version of the [*EOS Utility Instruction Manual*](http://www.canon.ca/support_images/RightNow_Images/Digital_Camera/EU2.2_W_EN.pdf). Newer versions are downloadable from Canon's websites, but are not accessible as direct links.

Comment: Can you expand a little on how to do it?

Comment: It's all in the *User Manual* for *EOS Utility*. To rewrite the entire instruction manual here is beyond the scope and size of a single answer on this site.